# Returning or inheriting a generic that contains a nested class

Tags: c#, generics, nested-generics

I am noticing some extremely strange behaviour when using a class layout that looks like this:

```
// Contents of assembly A:
public class MyParentClass
{
    public class NestedClass
    {
    }
}

// Contents of assembly B:
public class AnotherClass : List<MyParentClass.NestedClass>
{
}
```

I can add assembly A as a dependency of assembly B. This example will compile without any error messages, but when it comes to, for example, loading assembly B as a reference for unit testing, I will receive this error when it comes time to compile unit tests:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>        PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the
>        file specified.

The assembly that this code generates does actually work, and I can run through the generated DLL with Redgate Reflector and see my code as expected, but the unit tests refuse to load it.

I am almost positive that this issue is to do with the fact that I am calling a nested class that is in another assembly, and I will probably end up refactoring this design anyway, but I would really like to know why this does not work as expected. If there was a problem with using the classes in this fashion, I would expect the compiler to throw an exception.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: are you loading assembly A at the same time as B, in your unit test assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Is "Copy Local" enabled for that reference? I assume that your test project testing assembly B doesn't have a copy of assembly A. Setting "Copy Local" to true on the references should copy the assemblies, so that they can be found correctly when compiling (and finally running) the tests.

Comment: Actually, assembly B is loaded with the unit test project as well. In all cases, "Copy Local" is set to True, so I do not believe this is the issue. Good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is anything to do with nested classes - just a lack of transitive dependencies being surfaced in .NET.

Basically, if you're going to use `AnotherClass` in one project, you'll need to explicitly add a reference to both `AssemblyB` *and* `AssemblyA`. That way both should be copied and loaded appropriately.

If that doesn't help, you could try [enabling fusion logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I have added a reference to both assemblies in my unit test project, so that's not the issue. Nothing came up in the binding log window either, but I'd never come across that tool before so that's still something new I've learned. Thanks for that!

Comment: Last time I checked (some years ago) Fuslogvw.exe was a bit inflexible. So I rather spool my fusion logs to some folder.  Alter "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion", set ForceLog and LogFailures to 1 and set LogPath=C:\Temp\FusionLog and create that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error message in visual studio 2010 if your project has target framework set to "Framework 4 Client Profile" and the linked dll has a target Framework "Framework 4".

Check that in your project settings.

Comment: All my projects have the target of ".NET Framework 4". Thanks anyway :)